# how to create shortcode in wordpress

Tags: functions, shortcode

So I have the following code:

```
 <span class="delete"><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" href="<?php echo wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( array( 'action' => 'my-delete-product', 'product_id' => $post->ID ), my_get_navigation_url('products') ), 'my-delete-product' ); ?>"><?php _e( '삭제', 'my' ); ?></a> | </span>
```

It is a simple button.

I want to make this into a shortcode so that I can use it anywhere where appropriate.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your short code just few steps.

```
function short_codeFunction_name( $atts, $content=null ) {
    shortcode_atts( array(), $atts);
    $rowin = '<div class="row">'.do_shortcode( $content ) .'</div>';
    return $rowin;
}
add_shortcode( "your_shortcode_name", "short_codeFunction_name" );
```

1. Then you can access `[your_shortcode]Here your
       content[your_shortcode]` format inside the Post,page etc.
2. add this function inside function.php in active theme directory.
3. use inside your theme directory

Comment: You should not be using `extract()` at all :-)

Comment: Why.. reason being..

Comment: [This trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22400) should explain everything well, and also notice, all instances of `extract()` was removed from core and there was a cleanup in the codex as well to remove `extract()` from functions and examples. :-)

Comment: Okay.. thanx for update me..

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Wordpress API documents this very thoroughly. Check it out [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

And if you are feeling lazy, here is a [custom generator.](http://generatewp.com/shortcodes/)

If you have a specific question beyond that, comment below.